# How to disable default authentication on airflow 2.0.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, airflow-2.x

We are upgrading our airflow service to 2.0.1 deployed on AWS, However, after upgrading, it has default authentication page. [airflow2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxbHG.png)

We have already set authenticate and rbac to false in the configure file for our ansible deployment as suggested by other post online, but it did not solve the issue.

```
[webserver]
...
# Set to true to turn on authentication:
# https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/security.html#web-authentication
authenticate = False

# Filter the list of dags by owner name (requires authentication to be enabled)
filter_by_owner = False

# Filtering mode. Choices include user (default) and ldapgroup.
# Ldap group filtering requires using the ldap backend
#
# Note that the ldap server needs the "memberOf" overlay to be set up
# in order to user the ldapgroup mode.
owner_mode = user

# Default DAG view.  Valid values are:
# tree, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
dag_default_view = tree

# Default DAG orientation. Valid values are:
# LR (Left->Right), TB (Top->Bottom), RL (Right->Left), BT (Bottom->Top)
dag_orientation = LR

# Puts the webserver in demonstration mode; blurs the names of Operators for
# privacy.
demo_mode = False

# The amount of time (in secs) webserver will wait for initial handshake
# while fetching logs from other worker machine
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5

# By default, the webserver shows paused DAGs. Flip this to hide paused
# DAGs by default
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False

# Consistent page size across all listing views in the UI
page_size = 100

# Use FAB-based webserver with RBAC feature
rbac = False
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/webserver.html)

> To deactivate the authentication and allow users to be identified as Anonymous, the following entry in $AIRFLOW_HOME/webserver_config.py needs to be set with the desired role that the Anonymous user will have by default:

```
AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Admin'
```